# MobileFirst 7.0 Hybrid App missing Dojo components during compilation

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I've created a new hybrid app and added iPad as my environment. During compilation, I have unchecked the `Provide Library Resources` under `Dojo Library Request` menu but the `Dojo` components are not being copied to the iPad resources (www folder).

This is stopping the app to launch and I need to copy the components `(Dijit/Dojo/Dojox/Layers)` manually and I have to do it every time I do compilation. I haven't had this problem before.

What do I need to do so that the components will automatically be copied to the environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually put in your dojo lib the components that you intend on using. You can serve them remotely during development, but you should add the components that you actually intend on using in your app to your app.

Going forward I wouldn't be using Dojo anymore... It has been removed from MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, for example...

Comment: On my previous apps, I don't need to copy manually every time I compile the app. For my new project, I don't know why MobileFirst refreshes the folder /www/default inside the iPad environment every compilation.